# Find biggest number out of 3 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find of biggest of 3 numbers using python3.6. But its returning wrong value.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

a=input("Enter first number: ")
b=input("Enter second number: ")
c=input("Enter Third number: ")
if (a >= b) and (a >= c):
    largest=a
elif (b >= a) and (b >= c):
    largest=b
else:
    largest=c

print(largest, "is the greatest of all")
```

If I provide, a=15; b=10 and c=9
Expected output should be 15.

But I am getting actual output as 9.

Comment: You are comparing strings, not numbers. If you convert them to numbers, they will be compared as numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns strings. You need to convert the strings to class int to compare their numeric value:

```
a = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
```

In `string` comparisons, `9` is greater than `1`. You can try in the REPL:

```
>>> '9' > '111111111111111111'
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the max() builtin function of python: 
https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/python-max-function/19205

Comment: as @khelwood mentioned cast it to int -> int(a)

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment of [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) mentioned it `You are comparing strings, not numbers. – khelwood`. You should first cast the input values to integers (or float) and then compare them.

More about casting in python can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As khelwood pointed out in comment those inputs are used as strings.

try inserting this after input and its fixed:

```
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
c = int(c)
```